# Unity Instantiate всегда создает объект в одном месте, хотя я указываю совсем другие координаты

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Хочу чтоб создавался объект в разных местах локации, всего  4 точки, каждые 10 секунд я создаю объект с помощью instantiate но он всегда берет координаты префаба, хотя я указываю другие.

тут я создаю массив

```
private Vector3[] busters = new Vector3[4] { new Vector3(12f, 4f, 0f), new Vector3(4f, 5.5f), new Vector3(-9f, 7f), new Vector3(2f, 0.5f) };
```

Создаю объект,
buster - сам префаб, busters - массив Vector3

```
        int index = Random.Range(0, 3) ;
        Vector3 pos = busters[index];
        Instantiate(buster, pos, buster.transform.rotation);
```

Но объект создается с координатами префаба, что я сделал не так ? может не вижу какой-нибудь глупой ошибки...

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вместо buster.transform.rotation ->  Quaternion.identity. И все-таки лучше дописывать полностью Vector3

```
busters = new Vector3[4] { new Vector3(12f, 4f, 0f), new Vector3(4f, 5.5f, 0f), new Vector3(-9f, 7f, 0f), new Vector3(2f, 0.5f, 0f) }; 
Instantiate(buster, pos,  Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но дело было в анимации которая ставит все время одни и те же координаты